# can not set login logout session from android side when i am fetch data from server

Tags: java, android, odoo

i am work on **ODOO** base application and store user details to **ODOO** server but can not do login and logout from server that i have to manage from android side so i have use session management from android side.First i have login to my application login successfully but when second time login but details fetch of first user.how to logout from server side using android.

```
public class SharedPref {

    public SharedPreferences pref;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    public SharedPref(Context context) {
        this.pref = context.getSharedPreferences("P1m2h3spellbound", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }


    public void
    save(String key, String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void save(String key, Boolean value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void save(String key, int value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int load(String key, int def) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = pref.getInt(key, def);
        return i;
    }

    public String load(String key, String def) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strSaved = pref.getString(key, def);
        return strSaved;
    }

    public Boolean load(String key, boolean def) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isbool = pref.getBoolean(key, def);
        return isbool;
    }

    public void logoutapp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        boolean isZoomGuide = load("isZoomGuide", false);
        String ip = load("server_ip", "");
        String port = load("server_port", "");
        String db = load("server_db", "");
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        save("isZoomGuide", isZoomGuide);
        save("server_ip", ip);
        save("server_port", port);
        save("server_db", db);
        save("isServer", true);

    }
}
```

Comment: when you logout on app send a request to server for logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have an attribute in your class as `public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;` why are you creating a different `Editor` on every `save` method? Also in the `logoutapp` method you can use your editor.

I'm not getting what you are trying to do on this method, let's go step by step

```
public void logoutapp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    boolean isZoomGuide = load("isZoomGuide", false);
    String ip = load("server_ip", "");
    String port = load("server_port", "");
    String db = load("server_db", "");
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    save("isZoomGuide", isZoomGuide);
    save("server_ip", ip);
    save("server_port", port);
    save("server_db", db);
    save("isServer", true);

}
```

First you want to load and store some values stored on `SharedPreferences` into a variables.
Then you [`clear()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#clear()) I guess you know will remove all values from the preferences. Once commit is called, the only remaining preferences will be any that you have defined in this editor.

Then I see a [`commit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit()) but I'm not seeing you are storing its result, so you just can use [`apply()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()).
And then you save the values stored previously.

What I don't get is, do you need to remove all data from `SharedPreferences`? I don't think so, since you are storing the same values again. You can use [`remove(String key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#remove(java.lang.String)) to remove a specific item stored in your `SharedPreferences`.

Also I'd like to see how do you Log out from the app and how you Log in to the app to clear my doubts.